# Preventing Page Scroll - Disabling Drag

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Prevent Scroll Script

```
// left: 37, up: 38, right: 39, down: 40,
// spacebar: 32, pageup: 33, pagedown: 34, end: 35, home: 36
var keys = [37, 38, 39, 40];

function preventDefault(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault)
      e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = false;  
}

function keydown(e) {
    for (var i = keys.length; i--;) {
        if (e.keyCode === keys[i]) {
            preventDefault(e);
            return;
        }
    }
}

function wheel(e) {
  preventDefault(e);
}

function disable_scroll() {
  if (window.addEventListener) {
      window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
  }
  window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;
  document.onkeydown = keydown;
}

function enable_scroll() {
    if (window.removeEventListener) {
        window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
    }
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = document.onkeydown = null;  
}
```

### Usage

Call `disable_scroll();` to disable the page scrolling and `enable_scroll()` to enable the scrolling once again.

### The Problem

Unlike the Facebook modal box, you are still able to click and drag the page to scroll down.

### JSFiddle

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/2rud0aLm/

Comment: What the Facebook modal box does is that it also sets the body to hide any content overflow along the vertical (y) axis, therefore causing the scrollbar to disappear. Trickier, but not impossible, to implement as you have to check for the scroll position and then translate or offset the body content in order to preserve page position.

Comment: Before my Dreamweaver crashed last night part of my script checked the scroll position which is needed to display my modal box in the center of what the user can currently see. Once I re-implement this and know the position, what would be my next course of action?

Comment: 1) You would set `overflow` to hidden on the scrolling element (usually the body), and 2) start using a real editor - I suggest Sublime Text, WebStorm, Notepad++... anything but Dreamweaver ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Terry's first sentence provides a quick solution.  Simply change `overflow` to 'hidden' on the body to prevent scrolling.

You will also need to keep track of the window's scrolled position, and set it after changing the `overflow` property.

To prevent the mousewheel from being able to drag, attach a `scroll` event to the window, which sets `scrollTop` to the window's position when the modal dialog was opened:

```
function disable_scroll() {
  var top= $(window).scrollTop();
  $('body').css({
    overflow: 'hidden'
  });
  $(window).scrollTop(top);
  $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $(window).scrollTop(top);
  });    
}

function enable_scroll() {
  var top= $(window).scrollTop();
  $('body').css({
    overflow: ''
  });
  $(window).scrollTop(top);
  $(window).off('scroll');
}
```

Because `modal_close` and `modal_2` in your code has `href="#"`, the script will attempt to jump to the top of the page.  You can prevent that using `preventDefault`:

```
$('a[href=#]').on('click', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
});
```

### Fiddle

Comment: A simple trick indeed, but you will lose the user's vertical scroll position — might not be relevant to OP's case, but if the modal box is to be opened very far down in a rather long document, users will be sent all the way back to the document top :/

Comment: Good point!  I'll delete if I don't come up with a workaround.

Comment: Please check this [forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k6bm771m/) in which you'll see the result when the "click me" is at the bottom / elsewhere other than the top.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Don't delete it — it is a perfectly OK answer, and some people might even prefer a simple solution :) it really depends what people are looking for. For modal boxes that are only opened at the top of the viewport, your answer is perfectly legit :)

Comment: @RickHitchcock I've just tested with mouse wheel click and it allows to scroll. How can I prevent this please?

Comment: You've removed the `href="#'` from the close button removing the pointer. Without adding `cursor:pointer;` to the css, how can I simply have the `href="#"` preventing default jump?

Comment: You can use `preventDefault` on `click`, targeting `a[href=#]`.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Bare with me please, my head is now wrecking as dreamweaver closed on me and now a lot is broken. I'll comment/accept as answer soon thanks

Comment: Sorry about the delay! Good job I'm a bit of a beginner at PHP and posted most of my code on another question! All restored and script works perfecxtly thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is a rather rudimentary fix, and I will explain what I have changed in order to make it work:

1. **CSS**: For the overlay, you actually do not need to sniff the viewport dimensions. Simply setting to `position: fixed` with all four offsets, `top`, `left`, `bottom`, and `right` set to `0` will force it to fill the screen :)
2. **Markup**: Wrap all your page content in a container, say `<div class="page-wrap">`. This element is set to fixed position upon toggling of the modal box to prevent click-drag scrolling.
3. **JS**:

   - Set a global variable as `fromTop`, which we will use to track the user's scroll position.
   - When the modal box is opened, update scroll position. Hide vertical overflow of the body element, and vertically translate the entire page content, i.e. `.page-wrap` to preserve vertical location
   - When the modal box is closed, reverse what we have done above :) I have decided to use a callback at the end of `.fadeOut()` to prevent jerking.

With all that done, you don't even need to prevent the scroll event from firing, or listening to keypress events anymore. Without further ado, here is the code (here's the [functional demo](http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/mjq8gv29/)):

```
var fromTop;

$('.modal_2').click(function(){

    // Disable scroll and fade in modal box
    disable_scroll();
    $('.block_page').fadeIn();
    $('.modal_box').fadeIn();

    // Fetch current scroll position
    fromTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    // Hide overflowing vertical content
    $('body').css({
        'overflow-y': 'hidden'
    });
    $('.page-wrap').css({
        'transform': 'translateY(-'+fromTop+'px)'
    });
});
$('.modal_close').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // Enable scroll and fade out modal box
    $('.block_page').fadeOut(function() {
        // Wait for modal box to fade out before reversing things
        // Hide overflowing vertical content
        $('body').css({
            'overflow-y': 'visible'
        });
        $('.page-wrap').css({
            'transform': 'translateY(0)'
        });
        $(window).scrollTop(fromTop);
    });     
    $(this).parent().fadeOut();
    enable_scroll();        

});
```

Proof-of-concept fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/mjq8gv29/

---

Even better: use jQuery promises to check if fadeOut animations have been completed on both the `.block_page` element and the parent element. **This is exceptionally important if you want to set variable animation durations for either elements**:

```
$('.modal_close').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // Enable scroll and fade out modal box
    $('.block_page').fadeOut();     
    $(this).parent().fadeOut();

    // Use jQuery promises to check if all fadeOut animation has completed
    var p1 = $('.block_page').promise(),
        p2 = $(this).parent().promise();

    // When all animations have completed, reverse effects
    $.when(p1, p2).done(function() {
        // Hide overflowing vertical content
        $('body').css({
            'overflow-y': 'visible'
        });
        $('.page-wrap').css({
            'transform': 'translateY(0)'
        });
        $(window).scrollTop(fromTop);
    });
});
```

Advanced fiddle that uses jQuery `.promise()` deferred object: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/2rud0aLm/6/

Comment: Nice, disables the dragging upwards and with a bit of fiddling around I'll get it to work both ways :)

Comment: @TimMarshall Just added some more code to the bottom of my answer, to handle the scenario where the fadeOut animation durations are not identical (e.g. staggered) which might lead to jerky animation :) probably a *good-to-know* update, but still... ;)

Comment: How do I resolve the dragging down as your script stops dragging upwards but not downwards?

Comment: @TimMarshall If that is the case, you might want to reinject the code that deals with scrollwheel events. I suppose the dragging involves middle clicking and dragging, right?

Comment: No, until you mentioned and I just tested. I was referring to left-click + drag but now you've just pointed out another...

Comment: Using `position: fixed` on the `.page-wrap` element worked :) http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/2rud0aLm/6/